# Output of json array with boost::property_tree

Tags: c++, json, boost-propertytree

I wan't put to json data in std::unordered_map, for example this:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::vector<std::string>> data = {
    {"name", {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e"}},
    {"price", {"1.1", "2.2", "3.3", "4.4", "5.5"}},
    {"id", {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"}}
};
```

To this json:

[
{
"id": "1",
"price": "1.1",
"name": "a"
},
{
"id": "2",
"price": "2.2",
"name": "b"
},
{
"id": "3",
"price": "3.3",
"name": "c"
},
{
"id": "4",
"price": "4.4",
"name": "d"
},
{
"id": "5",
"price": "5.5",
"name": "e"
}
]

I tried put this map to boost::propetry_tree::ptree and using write_json function output this in std::cout:

```
size_t nrows = 5;

boost::property_tree::ptree pt;

for(size_t i = 0; i < nrows; i++) {
    boost::property_tree::ptree body_node;
    for(const auto& kv : data) {
        body_node.put(kv.first, kv.second[i]);
    }
    pt.push_back(std::make_pair("", body_node));
}

boost::property_tree::write_json(std::cout, pt);
```

I have this output:

{
"": {
"id": "1",
"price": "1.1",
"name": "a"
},
"": {
"id": "2",
"price": "2.2",
"name": "b"
},
"": {
"id": "3",
"price": "3.3",
"name": "c"
},
"": {
"id": "4",
"price": "4.4",
"name": "d"
},
"": {
"id": "5",
"price": "5.5",
"name": "e"
}
}

How I can change that output to expected?